# Getting a dictionary key that is an instance

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a complex data structure, essentially a dict where the keys are hashed instances.   If I only know the hashed value that equals the key, how can I get back the instance?  I can do it by brute force, but it seems I should be able to get the key/instance in O(1) time.

```
class Test:
        def __init__(self, foo, bar):
                self.foo = foo
                self.bar = bar
                self.arr = ["extra"]
        def __str__(self):
                return self.foo + self.bar
        def __hash__(self):
                return hash(str(self))
        def __eq__(self, other):
                return hash(self) == hash(other)

my_thing = Test("FOO", "BAR")

my_dict = dict()
my_dict[my_thing] = 1

for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
        if k == "FOOBAR":
                print k.arr
```

Edit: I want to be able to get the mutable data in the instance (in this case the array).  So that if I only know the hash of `"FOOBAR"` I would like to be able to get `["extra"]`, without having to traverse the entire dictionary matching keys (the for loop at the bottom)

Comment: `def __eq__(self, other):
                return hash(self) == hash(other)` that is bad: what about hash collision?

Comment: so you want to obtain the `my_thing` again?

Comment: that will never by true `if k == "FOOBAR":` you mean `if str(k) == "FOOBAR":` right?

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get a key/value out of a dict given `hash(key)` and not just `key`.

Comment: Dictionaries are not meant to allow you to get the corresponding key from a value (which is necessarily ambiguous anyway) in O(1) time.

Comment: I think OP thinks the dictionary only stores the hashes as its keys. You can see that this isn't true if you do `print(type(k))`.

Comment: @jean. yes it is sample code.

@Willem yup I want to be able to get `my_thing` back, so that I can access the mutable variables (in this case the array).

Comment: AFAIK you can't do a lookup in a dict given only the hash of the key you used to add the element, and not the key itself. If you need to lookup your instance given only that hash, you will need to maintain another dict whose key is the hash itself.

Comment: RE the latest edit, note that "FOOBAR" is not your hash; `hash("FOOBAR")` is your hash. "FOOBAR" is the string representation of your object. If you want to be able to use that string repr. as a key, you need to maintain a separate dict that uses that as the key. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The dict should map a key (foo, bar) to the data you want to retrieve. Here is one way you could implement this:

```
class Test(object):
    ...
    def key(self):
        return (self.foo, self.bar)

my_thing = Test("FOO", "BAR")
my_dict = {}
my_dict[my_thing.key()] = my_thing

print my_dict[("FOO", "BAR")].arr
```

Note that I modified your key function to avoid collisions like:

```
Test("FOO", "BAR") == Test("FOOB", "AR")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the string "FOOBAR" (for example) and you want to retrieve a key `k` in your dict for which `str(k) == "FOOBAR"`.

One way to do this is to just reconstruct a new Test object that will have the same string representation and use that for your lookup:

```
my_thing = my_dict(Test("FOO", "BAR"))
```

But this is inefficient and creates a dependency between object creation and your string representation.

If this string representation has its own intrinsic value as a key, you can just maintain your dict (or another dict) keyed by string instead:

```
my_index = dict()
my_index[str(my_thing)] = my_thing
```

That way, you can lookup your value given the string only:

```
print my_index["FOOBAR"].arr
```